# Common location for kubernetes config files

Tags: kubernetes

I got this structure:

```
├── root
│   ├── app A
│   ├── app B
│   ├── app C
```

The root folder is initialized as git folder so I can easily push the whole project. Now I am wondering where to place the `kubernetes yaml` files.
My idea would be something like this:

```
    ├── root
    │   ├── app A
    │   ├── app B
    │   ├── app C
    │   ├── kubernetes.conf.d
            ├── appA.yaml
```

**Question**: is there is a common location to place the config files for kubernetes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely subjective and you should do whatever works for you. My preference, however, is:

```
# Each application has
- opt
  - kubernetes
    - deployment.yaml
  - helm
    - values.yaml
```

I like using `./opt`, as it is familiar to most with Unix experience.

Comment: Thanks! I also forgot that the cluster has nothing to do with the local application, at least not the way I expected ;D